# Supercap backup power - delayed power on

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to figure out how to make a backup power that will allow my SBCs to safely power down in case of power outage. What I thought to use are supercaps (2 in series for 5.5V) that will first charge before sending power to SBC.

[image: Schematic]

Idea is that on power connected to 5V rail FET is turned off and capacitors will charge through shunt resistor R1. R2 and R3 create a voltage divider that is used by opamp to detect when charging current drops below set level. Since I don't need perfect values, pins 1 and 5 of LM741 are NC. So when charing with high current, source voltage will drop charing at 2A then when it hits 5V it will charge with CV until current drops to around 100-100mA. Then opamp output switches to low pulling Q1 gate low and turning on FET. This in turn turns on Q2 which will keep Q1 gate to ground until voltage drops to very low level.

Now I think it should work, but I'm not sure about R4 R5 and R6 values, also, not really sure what FET and transistor to use. I also wonder what will be the best way to check if we are running from that 5V supply or from caps.

Comment: To tell if you're on 5V rail, or running from caps, check the voltage drop across R1. When caps are discharging, rail will be lower V than caps; all other times, the rail V will be >= caps.

Comment: Your circuit simply does not work. 1) A 741 won't work at 5 V. 2) The -ve input of the op-amp is at just 0.1 V so does not do what you want it to do. 3) You can't connect Q2 Collector to the op amp output. 4) As soon as you have more than 0.1 V on the supercaps the op-amp output would be high. 5) I assume you load is operating at 5 V (before the power fail) and this will back feed (through the FET intrinsic diode) to the charge line ...so you don't have a 2 A charge limit at all.

Comment: in spice that `1M` resistor is 1 milliohm - probably not intentional gotta write it a `1Meg`

Comment: @JackCreasey 
1) Yeah, I missed that, let's treat it as opamp that works on 5V.
2) I compare voltage across 1Ohm shunt to 100mV and detect when it drops below that level so that supercaps are mostly charged.
3) Ok, how to do that connection then? Via transistor?
4) Hmm... I hoped I will detect drop on R1 by connecting there.
5) It won't go back since load will be only drawing power and power source is connected before FET. 2A limit will be done wither via lab power supply or by a chip.

Comment: Supercap supercap supercap supercap supercap stooop!, why? you hear that god forsaken word over and over and over again, mostly by people with no background in electronics, and for what?`why do you actually think that you need, or have any good use of, a supercap? sure they have some really usefull properties in a very limited specialized few applications, while in most other applications they are useless, but science "pop culture" has made the word "supercap" a household word, and now every hobby electronics enthusiast thinks he needs a supercap in his eggwatch, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: @Vinzent long, pointless and very misplaced rant. The supercaps are perfect as short-term power backup, which is exactly the case of this application. Nothing "very limited" about it too. Pretty much any log-keeping embedded application with manual power switch would benefit from similar design. The alternatives, like rechargeable batteries, are neither more reliable, nor economical.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simpler diode circuit for this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxnVOE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the diode drops are too much for you, use active diodes, perhaps using LM5050s
[image]

Comment: Well, problem here is that whole circuit including charging and load will draw ~3.5A while I want it whole to be limited to 2A. Also, since my load will be a SBC, can't really undervolt it or it will do funny things.

Comment: @Migol I figured you would, but that functionality would need to be after the above.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the troubles to shoot:

1. Q1 is the wrong way around. You want to have its source connected to the power supply side, with the load at its drain.
2. Q2 will short circuit the op-amp output to ground, when it's on. As it stands, once that op-amp that output goes low, it's stuck there forever by brute force of Q2. That may be what you want, but if so, don't use any op-amp that is able to pull its output high, which would lead to contention. Usually you would be controlling Q2's base with the op-amp, not its collector. Please correct me if this "latching" action by Q2 is what you intended.
3. Your 2A 5V supply will be overloaded when the capacitors are discharged, since the voltage across R1 will by 5V, which will *try* (and fail) to draw \$I=\frac{5\rm V}{1\rm \Omega} = 5\rm A\$
4. When the power supply goes away, all current drawn from C1 and C2 will have to pass via R1. If the SBC is drawing 2A, then its supply voltage will suddenly drop from 5V to \$5\rm{V} - 2\rm{A} \times 1\rm\Omega = 3V\$
5. The 741 is a bad choice for this application, its input voltage range does not include (or even get close to) the power supply potentials, and neither does its output. Think comparator, like the LM393.
6. The op-amp's inverting and non-inverting inputs are connected in such a way as to switch the FET *off* when the capacitors are charged. I can't tell if this is deliberate because your intention was to invert with Q2, but it's not clear to me.

Usually at this point I'd have a bunch of suggestions, but the big deal-breaker here is that voltage lost across R1 when powered from the supercaps. I'd suggest using diodes to steer current from the two voltage sources, but then you'd need a power supply half a volt or so *above* 5.0V.

An additional MOSFET to switch in the those caps seems to be necessary to jump this hurdle, but then you'd need some extra logic or comparing, to prevent the output being enabled when the caps are discharged, and to prevent  both MOSFETs from switching on simultaneously.

Sorry to say, I don't see any simple fixes here.